# Python. How to get formatting styles from xlsx file

Tags: python, parsing, xlsx

Good afternoon.
I have a file... For example, in this file there are 4 identical sentences, but they have different formatting styles.

1. In the first sentence, one word is in bold
2. In the second sentence, one word is highlighted in red
3. In the third sentence, one word is oversized (say 16px instead of 10px)
4. No different.

How can you parse this file and get the data starting with what letter the text formatting begins and what letter this formatting ends with?
And what kind of formatting (color, font size, etc.)

**All this needs to be done in Python.**

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library, there's a section *Working with styles* that may be what you need.

Comment: As far as I understand. I can track there if the whole cell has been painted red. And how exactly to find out the coordinates if the last letter was highlighted in the word "cat". Well, it's the same with all other styles.